# Authentication plugin 'mysql_clear_password' cannot be loaded in Navicat

Tags: mysql, database, macos, navicat

I try to connect with my database and use Navicat with MacOS , but I get an error and not able to connect. I tried many different things but not able to connect yet. any help really appreciates and it's really great to help me.

Error :

> Connection Failed
>
> Authentication plugin 'mysql_clear_password' cannot be loaded:
> dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/mysql_clear_password.so, 2): image
> not found

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the same error in my MySQLWorkbench, went through the available ui configs and ticked the

*Enable Cleartext Authentication Plugin*

Steps need to be taken:

1. Open *Connect to Database* window
2. Choose *Advanced* option
3. Tick *Enable Cleartext Authentication Plugin* option

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try starting Navicat from the terminal. This assumes the app is 'Navicat Premium Essentials'.

```
LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=y /Applications/Navicat\ Premium\ Essentials.app/Contents/MacOS/Navicat\ Premium\ Essentials
```

This solved the issue for me with Sequel Pro. See: https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2247#issuecomment-144567527